# Standard containers for limited types in Ada?

Tags: types, containers, ada

Very simple question: are there any standard containers for storing instances of limited types? I haven't been able to find any --- all the standard containers I've found so far require unlimited types. While it's easy enough to roll my own (and indeed I have), it's fiddly, tedious and error-prone, and I don't think I should have to.

Comment: There aren't any, and looking at AI95-302 it appears that these weren't even considered.  You might want to check out http://www.stephe-leake.org/ada/sal.html which has some containers for limited types.

Comment: The straightforward solution would be to instantiate standard Containers with access-to-limited-type[‘Class], which is what you’d need to do internally I think. There remains the issue of freeing instances on removal from the Container.